# Highcharts gantt variable Y axis size

Tags: highcharts, angular2-highcharts, highcharts-gantt

I am creating a Gantt chart on Angular using highcharts angular. An example of what I am creating can be found here: JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/esantiagovieira/mb2eovfu/

The chart options are quite simple, nothing facing:

```
chart: {
    height: 400
  },
  yAxis: {
    uniqueNames: true,
    max: 10,
   
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointWidth: 18,
      
    }
  },
})
```

My Gantt series has unique labels to group different data series on the same Gantt row. When more than one series get into the same row, the row height increases to accommodate both series points. The problem is that the height is applied to every other row even if it is not required. This behavior is creating a lot of whitespaces that I want to eliminate

Does anyone know a way to configure the row height for this scenario? My data does have a property that lets me know when a row of the Gantt will have more than 1 line, and I could use that property to set the row height, but I was unable to find a solution on highcharts that allow me to inform the height of each row, that is what I need help with.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour occurs due to an issue related to the enabled `uniqueNames` option. You can track it and find possible workarounds at the following thread:
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11796